# PHP: Remote MySQL connections very slow

Tags: php, mysql, performance, cpanel

I have two servers, both running CentOS 5.7 and cPanel-CURRENT. One is x86 and the other is x64. Both are using Apache 2.2.21, PHP 5.3.8 and MySQL 5.1.

If I query the local database on any one of the servers, the results are returned instantly. In this instance a few thousand results are being returned. However running the same query from one server to another and the query takes 10+ seconds to complete.

If I use MySQL Workbench 5.2 to query the remote database from my workstation with the same query, it completes in less than a second, which makes me think there's a problem with PHP or something else server-related.

Has anyone else encountered this issue before and know how to resolve it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try mysql_pconnect()  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php mayb it will help

Comment: Using persistent connections doesn't help. The query still takes the same time to complete.

Comment: May be your databases differ a bit? E.g. not all indexes on local machine exist on remote server. Php work good with remote mysql server, there probably some other problem. What about network connection? `Ping` remote server.

Comment: If I use MySQL Workbench on my local PC to connect to the remote database over the same connection, it's fine.

Comment: Please clarify: Are you using pdo from the php script?, are you entering a hostname or ip address to connect to the mysql server? have you run a query and got the actual completion time of the query or the time to display output?

Comment: what does your network setup look like? Running through a hub or older switches can be a real bitch on throughput.

Comment: please paste the connect line from PHP and also please let me know if the systems are using selinux

Comment: What's the internet speed of both connections (web server and your machine)? Try fiddler or Wireshark to analyze what's going on on the network.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**First guess:**

It might be a DNS issues and you may use `--skip-name-resolve` option in `my.cnf` or you may use only IP addresses in the MySQL grant tables.

**Second guess:**

It might be a problem with the security level and I suggest to temporarily `disable selinux` or the firewall and run the test again.

Comment: I'm using the IP address to connect to the remote server in both PHP and MySQL Workbench. Also the "--skip-name-resolve" is in the config file and the server has been restarted. Finally selinux is disabled (one of the requirements for running cPanel) and I tried disabling the firewall but to no avail.

Comment: and you noticed any improvements? Can you please tell me what amount of time the connect function takes. I wondering what exactly is time consuming which is not actually clear from your question.

Comment: In the config file, it should be "skip-name-resolve" not "--skip-name-resolve" - the preceding dashes are only if it's used as a parameter when you start the mysqld service.

Comment: And, the line "skip-name-resolve" should be under [mysqld] (or at least in that block)

Comment: I meet the same issue. Try to see /etc/resolve.conf, and ping the configured DNS server. Maybe cannot access to it.

Comment: BINGOOOO!!! skip-name-resolve did the trick for me. I was getting a consistent 10 seconds delay overhead in every connection.

Answer (score 5):

I had this exact issue with a PHP/MySQL application.

Just wanted to share that adding "skip-name-resolve" to my.ini fixed it for me. I was a little confused by this since my application on desktop 1 was accessing desktop 2 (mysql) using IP address. I am going between two Windows 7 desktops.